# Add analytics event to log each ViewController's name in the project

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns

I have a project in which I need to log an analytics event whenever any View Controller (log the name of the View Controller) comes on screen.

I was trying to avoid littering all of my existing View Controller classes with call to the analytics SDK.

I tried making an AnalyticsViewController and all my View Controllers would subclass this View Controller, and then I add analytics event in AnalyticsViewController class's viewDidLoad method. But the problem with this approach is that AnalyticsViewController does not which child View Controller is the call coming from.

I am using Swift 3.0. I believe that Swift with its powerful language features should be able provide me with an abstraction of some sorts.

Is there any way through this problem without littering all the View Controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track. Making a UIViewController parent class is a good idea.

In viewDidLoad method you can just add this:

```
let className = NSStringFromClass(self.classForCoder)
```

It will give you the name of current loaded view controller and then you can use that name in your event to specify which view controller was actually loaded.

Edit: added example.
So your parent's viewDidLoad would look something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let className = NSStringFromClass(self.classForCoder)
    sendEvent(withViewControllerName: className)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @JPetric is an amazing starting point. I just had to do a little modification to get it to work.

I've put this in my AnalyticsViewController to retrieve the name of the current subclass.

```
private func currentClassName() -> String? {
        return NSStringFromClass(self.classForCoder).components(separatedBy: ".").last
    }
```